# How to use new project to update existing app?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a Universal iOS app that has been in the App Store for two years now. I am working on a massive update for it. I have learned a lot since then and I feel that the best thing for me to do is to rewrite the app from the ground up. I can just strip out the app but I would rather start from scratch with a new Xcode project and submit it as an update.

However, I'm not sure if this will work. What do I need to change in the plist and other settings so that this new project will be recognized as an update to the existing one? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just be able to use the App ID/Provisioning profile of the existing app when you develop the new one.

In XCode, you'd set the Bundle ID to whatever the app's identifier is, and update CFBundleVersion and CFBundleShortVersionString to reflect the current version of the app.

Keep in mind that you *can't add* to the required device capabilities (meaning make it more restrictive), so it has to match what they were for the old version.